# Android Studio: Can't associate .mp3 files with a file type

Tags: java, android, mp3

so I am new to Android development; for some reason when I tried to add sound (from a .mp3) file, it will not start. It needs me to associate the file with a file type.

What would I use? I don't see any file types for 'sound'

Comment: Better post it here http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please add some code, of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that [mp3 files are not allowed as sound files in Android Studio](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2hnjyf/quick_question_with_android_studio_and_mp3_files/). So I converted my mp3 file into a wav file using [this website](http://audio.online-convert.com/fr/convertir-en-wav). And then I had another error: "name of the file should not have uppercase letter". I changed the name of my file to lowercase and everything is fine, now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, I needed to create a new Android Resource Directory into the directory "res". I called it "raw". So I pasted the .mp3's file into it, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add raw folder in res directory by doing right click on res>New>Android Resource Directory>Select Resource Type as raw> press OK. Copy ur audio/video file (the file should name in lowercase with no space or any special characters) to raw folder...while saving audio/video file it may ask for saving as txt file...go ahead save it as txt....then access this audio/video from java file...Do play it on emulator..

### //myaudio is my audio file name

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.myaudio);

mMediaPlayer.start();

mMediaPlayer.pause();

Answer (score 0):

In res create raw folder with say `song` named mp3 file
then use the following code:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to associate .mp3 file Android can play it without associating. You have to rename .mp3 file such that it does not include capital letter and minus(-) symbol.

First create Android Resource Directory and preferably name it raw and resource type should be raw and use underscore and lowercase letters while naming mp3 file. That is it!